# Configuring the region for the Job ads panel

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

The Job ads panel in Stack Overflow shows jobs close to where you are currently located (based on your IP address I believe). This is great, apart from...

- When you're on vacation (and using Stack Overflow), as it shows jobs in that area rather than your home region
- If you're planning to relocate in the near future (and likely be seeking a new job), in which case it would be useful if it showed jobs in that region

To help in both of these edge cases, how about having a profile setting that allows a user to configure the region from which they would prefer to see job ads?

Comment: It's still planned, and part of the infrastructure is implemented. It almost made it to the top of the priority list a couple times in the last few months, only to get bumped by other features/experiments. It'll happen soonish.